# Choosing data source when serving vector tiles from GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, performance

I am about to set up a basemap with some 20-30 layers, served as a group layer in GeoServer. Output format is pbf vector tiles.

Should I stick with postgis or shapefiles if I want best possible performance?

Will use some attributes for styling but the attributes will be slimmed to a minimum.

The layer will be rendered by OpenLayers.

Comment: I would say avoid vector tiles if speed is an issue, use prerendered image tiles

Answer (score 4):

For best performance I would recommend to serve your vector tiles as Mapbox Vector Tiles (MVT).

[MVT](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/) uses PBF and is a very efficient vector format. You could serve your layers directly from PostGIS using [ST_AsMVT](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_AsMVT.html), but more efficiently you should export them to static files.

The best way is to offer them as XYZ tiles from directories, but in case you have a huge amount of zoom levels and layers you also could package them as MBTiles files and use [tileserver-php](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php) to serve them as pbf vector tiles which [Openlayers can use](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html).